# iPhone calendar "+" button to add events grayed out

Tags: iphone, calendar

In my iPhone calendar, the "+" sign is grayed out and will not allow me to add an event.  I have tried going to calendars in iCloud (*Settings*, *iCloud*, turn on *Calendars*) and calendars was on, so I turned it off, waited a few seconds, and turned it back on; no success.  I closed all programs and rebooted the phone and still was not able to add an event into calendar,  also went to *Settings*, *Mail, Contact, Calendar* and all is on there as well.

Comment: Check iCloud memory? Try changing your default calendar to a Google account or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I have Iphone 4s and this happens once or twice a year.I ignore signing in my emaail account when asked.This time I signed in to my account as if I wanted to send to my Calender and the plus sign turned back to red and now works.I don't normally sync to my account.I just keep info on phone.